# how can I bind jquery methods to htmls tags which are added after the page have been loaded?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a button which adds rows to my table.
but the property of Delete button dose work as it has been added after readyFucntion have been called

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the elements are all added to a common ancestor, use event-delegation with `on()` (in jQuery 1.7+):

```
$('#commonAncestorID').on('click', '.newElementsClass', function(){
    // do something when the elements with 'newElementsClass' are clicked
});
```

Or using `delegate()` (jQuery < 1.7):

```
$('#commonAncestorID').delegate('.newElementsClass', 'click', function(){
    // do something when the elements with 'newElementsClass' are clicked
});
```

You can, of course, bind delegated events to any element that's an ancestor of the newly-added elements, such as the `body` or to the `document` itself; but binding to the closest common parent prevents the events bubbling all the way through the DOM, which avoids needless performance penalties.

References:

- [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Thankx a lot @david can u also tell do i need to write this code in readyMethod or i can write it out side also

Comment: It should be done in either `$(document).ready(function(){ /* in here */});`, or be in a script tag before the `</body>` closing tag. Otherwise the elements your binding to won't be there, yet.